# Get result from count matched different request form two table mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

sorry for my bad english

i tired have problem, i want to matched field in 2 table

table 1

```
CREATE TABLE `may` (
  `idKEYWORD` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `faku` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`ipk` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`per` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`has` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`sem` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`jur` varchar(45) NOT NULL
);

table 2
CREATE TABLE `matched_may` (
`idmayKEYWORD` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `namemay` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `req_faku` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `req_jur` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `req_ipk` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `req_perkap` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `req_has` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `req_sem` varchar(50) NOT NULL

);
```

in php like this but i need ini mysql because i have so much record i want to use order by total match and use limit

```
if($red->faku == $res->req_faku OR $res->req_faku == '') $tot[] = 1;
if($red->jur == $res->req_jur OR $res->req_jur == '') $tot[] = 1;
if($red->ipk >= $res->req_ipk OR $res->req_ipk == '') $tot[] = 1;
if($red->per >= $res->req_perkap OR $res->req_perkap == 0) $tot[] = 1;
if($red->has <= $res->req_has OR $res->req_has == 0) $tot[] = 1;
if($red->sem == $res->req_sem OR $res->req_sem == 0) $tot[] = 1;
```

i need to get 4 or more matched from 6 request

sorry i want to get result like

```
namemay | matched
name1   | 4
name2   | 5
name3   | 4
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results do wonders for explaining what you want to do.

Comment: what?? It's not clear what you want to achieve...
Where is the sql? Where's the rest of php code?

Comment: sorry i already edit it

Comment: Why do you use an array `$tot` in the PHP? Why not `$tot += 1` to add to a total?

Comment: it just sugestion sir, i use in php i will get echo count($tot) from total matched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm guessing what you want to do, you need to join the tables. Then you can compare the columns from the two tables, and add up the number of matches.

```
SELECT namemay, 
    (req_faku = '' OR req_faku = faku) + (req_jur = '' OR req_jur = jur) 
    + (req_ipk = '' OR req_ipk <= ipk) + (req_perkap = 0 OR req_perkap = per)
    + (req_has = 0 OR req_has >= has) + (req_sem = 0 OR req_sem = sem) AS matched
FROM may
JOIN matched_may ON idKEYWORD = idmayKEYWORD
HAVING matched >= 4
```

Comparison expressions return `1` when they're true, `0` when false, so you can use addition to get the total columns that matches.

Comment: thank you so much sir it use without ON idKeyword = idmayKEYWORD, sorry im forgot i use where in idkeyword